# Django makemigrations adds a new file to migrations folder, however, migrate command doesn't do anything

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I just added a new field to a database model in my django app. When I run makemigrations, I see that a new migration file is created, however, running `python manage.py migrate` doesn't do anything.

```py
(twisto-pU_5F16G-py3.10) ➜  twisto git:(burakhan-ze-204-trverification-serrvisine-gizlilik-politikasi-eklenmesi) python manage.py makemigrations customer
Migrations for 'customer':
  apps/customer/migrations/0221_trupgraderequest_privacy_policy_doc_uuid.py
    - Add field privacy_policy_doc_uuid to trupgraderequest
(twisto-pU_5F16G-py3.10) ➜  twisto git:(burakhan-ze-204-trverification-serrvisine-gizlilik-politikasi-eklenmesi) ✗ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: abtest, account, accounting, admin, api, auth, banking, campaign, card, career, cash, change_requests, collectora, contenttypes, customer, dealerpanel, documents, feedback, gdpr, heureka, homepage, kyc, land, partner, postdeploy, product_category, psp, request, risk, saltedge, scoring, sessions, shopping, spi, support, treehorn
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check table `django_migrations`.

If you have file in "migrations" folder and migrate does not do anything, that means one of two reasons:

- migration is already in database;
- you have deleted previous migration file with same number, so Django ignores it.

Answer (score -1):

can you try delete file in folder migartons like 0001_.py all , and do migrations again.

Comment: You will need to drop db also, because `django_migrations` in existing database will be corrupted with such deleting.